# MSBuild Console - How to Add Additional Include Directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, console

I have setup a new server machine. I setup windows sdk, .net framework sdk, and checkout my visual studio from svn. I would like to build my application using msbuild but it keeps asking me where the "windowsx.h" file is. I do not want to setup any visual studio ide. How can I make msbuild see windows sdk include folder using console?

Answer (score 0):

With a normal install of Visual Studio you get a shortcut to a Visual Studio prompt. This sets all environment variables so you can use the compiler (and other tools) from the command line. First you can try to run msbuild from such a prompt. If that works add the necessary folders to the msbuild settings.

Comment: Can you please provide a xml example for adding neccessary folder to a msbuild file?

Comment: A vcxproj file is an msbuild script, so just make changes in the GUI and see how they end up in the vcxproj.